# ec2-upload-bundle: Signature version 4 authentication failed, trying different signature version, which fails too

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

```
# ec2-upload-bundle --access-key AKxxxx --secret-key xxxx --bucket something-i-own --manifest image1.img.manifest.xml
Digest::Digest is deprecated; use Digest
Digest::Digest is deprecated; use Digest
Digest::Digest is deprecated; use Digest
Digest::Digest is deprecated; use Digest
Digest::Digest is deprecated; use Digest
Signature version 4 authentication failed, trying different signature version
ERROR: Error talking to S3: Server.NotImplemented(501): A header you provided implies functionality that is not implemented
```

This is: ec2-ami-tools 1.5.7 on Arch Linux latest, running on an EC2 instance.

I understand the Digest related messages are about an obsolete Ruby API that however still works. The NotImplemented is more concerning ...

How can I upload my bundle?

Comment: Switch from the old, per-service cli tools to the newer unified awscli? And see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/bundle-instance.html.

Comment: This seems to be Windows VMs only? I cannot find anything equivalent for Linux VMs in those tools.

Comment: Apologies, was not aware of that limitation. Are you running this in eu-central-1 (hence v4 signing)? If this process works in other regions then I'd raise an issue with AWS.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving admin permissions to current user which you are using.
Go to IAM->select the user->permissions-> attach policy as "AdministratorAccess"
Now run the command again in ec2 instance and hopefully it will work.

Comment: Administrator access is not secure and thus should not be used for PROD.  To demonstrate, here is what the AWS portal applies when one follows the instructions given in your answer: `{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}`